# Combining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

```
Table1: ID,Name,some more columns
Table2: ID
Table3: Name
```

I want get output from table1, whose IDs are present in Table2.IDs & whose Name are present in Table3.Name.

In other words, select data which is present in ALL the 3 tables.

For ex:

Table1:

```
1 John
2 Will
3 Michael
```

Table2:

```
1
```

Table3:

```
Will
```

The output should be

```
1 John
2 Will
```

Comment: Your output shows 2 rows, but table2 doesn't have ID 2, and table3 doesn't have name Will - did you ask for **data which is present in ALL the 3 tables**? That is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JOINs.

Your description and your sample output do not match, so I'll give you one example for each.

Based on your description, it should be 2 INNER JOINs:

```
select table1.id, table1.name
from table1
inner join table2 on table2.id = table1.id
inner join table3 on table3.name = table1.name
```

Based on your output, it should be 2 OUTER JOINS with a WHERE clause specifying that at least one of the 2 joins was satisfied:

```
select table1.id, table1.name
from table1
left outer join table2 on table2.id = table1.id
left outer join table3 on table3.name = table1.name
where table2.id is not null or table3.name is not null
```

Comment: Nice catch on the INPUT/OUTPUT difference. Clear answer to ambiguous question.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as answer, but the query takes long time (although tables are indexed), is there any way we can improve the speed of this query?

Comment: Which query are you using? The inner joins or the outer joins?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected results, it looks like you want rows from Table1 that match either Table2 OR Table3, so you'll want to use LEFT JOINs.

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name
    from Table1 t1
        left join Table2 t2
            on t1.ID = t2.ID
        left join table3 t3
            on t1.Name = t3.Name
    where t2.ID is not null 
        or t3.Name is not null
```